# Flutter WebView retain state of widget to prevent reload

Tags: flutter, flutter-inappwebview, webview-flutter

I want to open a Webview on button click and after coming back from webview clicking on the same button, Webview should not be reloaded.

To achieve this I have tried `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` but It works majorly with PageView not stand-alone like when opened through another Widget using `Navigator.push`.